# JSON2HTML - Select tag being stripped in JSON object

Tags: jquery, javascript, json2html

I am facing an issue in converting following html code to json:

```
<div class="control" >
    <label>Caption</label><br>
    <select name="" class="dropdowntag">
        <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
        <option value="Option2">Option2</option>    
    </select>
</div>
```

In this resultant JSON, the **select** tag is missing, following is the result that I get from the transform builder provided in json2html site.

```
{"tag":"div","class":"control","children":[
  {"tag":"label","html":"Caption"},
  {"tag":"br","html":""}, [
     {"tag":"option","value":"Option1","html":"Option1"},
     {"tag":"option","value":"Option2","html":"Option2"}
  ]
]}
```

If I remove the outer div I am getting the json properly. Following is the modified html and its json result:

```
<label>Caption</label><br>
<select name="" class="dropdowntag">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>    
</select>

[
   {"tag":"label","html":"Caption"},
   {"tag":"br","html":""},
   {"tag":"select","class":"dropdowntag","name":"","children":[
      {"tag":"option","value":"Option1","html":"Option1"},
      {"tag":"option","value":"Option2","html":"Option2"}
   ]}
]
```

Not able to figure it out the reason for this issue.

**Note:** If I change the select tag to some other valid html tag or just give any other name than select it works fine.

Following are the version of jquery and json2html plugin used for this:

1. jquery-1.11.1
2. jquery-ui-1.11.0
3. json2html - current version available to download.

Following is the link to json2html plugin site:
[json2html](http://json2html.com/)
The builder tab in this page provides the option to build the transformer based on html.

Comment: which plugin you are using to convert html2json? Can you share what your tried (converting html to json)?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question now with the details that you have asked for...

Comment: Probably a bug, I would contact the author.

Answer (score 2):

The correct transform should be

```
{"tag":"div","class":"control","children":[
  {"tag":"label","html":"Caption"},
  {"tag":"br","html":""},
  {"tag":"select","class":"dropdowntag","name":"","children":[
    {"tag":"option","value":"Option1","html":"Option1"},
    {"tag":"option","value":"Option2","html":"Option2"}
  ]}
]}
```

I've verified that it doesn't work on json2html.com, looks like the DOM method to convert the transform doesn't seem to like select for some reason.  Thanks for picking up on this and I'll look into it